# Google Maps API testing

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I know there are many other topics that have the problem with the Google Maps API displaying a grid instead of the map, and that is the problem I am having as well.

The difference is that I have had mine working before. I followed a bunch of tutorials and signed my application and all of that stuff, but a few days later the map went back to the grid.

I can just generate another release token, but I don't want to have to do that every time the map displays a grid, and the debug key isn't working like it should.

What do you all suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you signed the build, did you update the key which the Google Maps use?

Because if not you will get a blank map. 
You will need to generate a new Google Maps API key with the keystore you used to sign the build and use this for the signed build.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

You will then notice the maps will not work when built in Eclipse using the debug keystore but will when exported and signed. It's an annoying process.

Comment: Ok, so I can't view the map while in Eclipse if I don't have my finalized version yet?

Comment: You can, you will just need to swap out the Maps API Key. Best thing to do is have the key in the strings.xml file. Use the debug key when building in Eclipse. Use the release key when exporting the app.